# Show/hide multiple elements on hover with JQuery and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is what I have so far:

```
<div style = "position: relative;">
<a href = "#games">
<div class="sidenavOff">
<img src = "images/card_normal.png" />
<img src = "images/category_icons/icon_games.png" style = "position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 40px;" />
<img src = "images/category_titles/title_games.png" style = "position: absolute; top: 160px; left: 40px;" />
</div>
<div class = "sidenavOver">
<img src = "images/hover/card_hover.png" />
<img src = "images/category_titles/title_games.png" style = "position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 40px;" />
<img src = "images/hover/card_hover_separator.png" style = "position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 40px;" />
Show a bunch of text here
<img src = "images/button_start_normal.png" style = "position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 40px;" />
/div>
</a>
</div>
```

So card.png is a notecard that has multiple transparent images overlayed on top of it. When the mouse is away from the card, it has icon_games.png and title_games.png showing on the card. I want it so that when the mouse hovers over card.png, icon_games.png, or title_games.png (in other words, whenever the mouse pointer is in the card), the card displays the elements title_games.png, card_hover_separator.png, a text description, and button_start_normal.png, in that order vertically (and the positioning of this should be editable as it will likely be different than the images displayed when not hovering).

This is my jquery code (I've never used it before so I'm pretty sure this is off. I don't quite understand it):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(“div.sidenavOff”).mouseover(function(){
$(this).removeClass().addClass(“sidenavOver”);
}).mouseout(function(){
$(this).removeClass().addClass(“sidenavOff”);
});
});
```

In a more understandable format, without hover:

http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/7026/screenshot20130606at122.png

With hover:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/855/screenshot20130606at122.png/

Comment: You've told us what your end goal is and your HTML, but what have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: I didn't know what to do with jquery since I've never used it before. I tried this but I'm pretty sure this is completely off: '$(document).ready(function() {
$(“div.sidenavOff”).mouseover(function(){
$(this).removeClass().addClass(“sidenavOver”);
}).mouseout(function(){
$(this).removeClass().addClass(“sidenavOff”);
});
});'

Comment: What about the classes? Can you post them as well? When `mouseneter` card_normal.png, you want to change other two images, right?

Comment: I didn't define the classes, I thought I could just treat it like an ID and call it whatever I wanted to call it :/ Sorry, first time with HTML also!

Comment: When mouseenter card_normal.png, icon_games.png, and/or title_games.png, I want it to change to everything under sidenaveOver. Screenshots shown in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

> This is my jquery code [...]. I don't quite understand it

```
$(document).ready(function () {/* function body */});
```

When `document` (as a jQuery object `$`) is [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), invoke a *function* as described by `/* function body */`

```
$("div.sidenavOff")
```

Use jQuery `$` to get all *HTMLElements* that match the CSS Selector `div.sidenavOff`

```
.mouseover(function () {
    $(this).removeClass().addClass("sidenavOver");
})
```

When the mouse goes over one of these elements ([`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)), remove the *class* `undefined` (as nothing between brackets, [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)), then add the *class* `sidenavOver` ([`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)) to the element that the mouse is over (`this`). *class* here can be understood as meaning the same as the *HTML* attribute *class*; `<a class="xyz">`

```
.mouseout(function () {
    $(this).removeClass().addClass("sidenavOff");
})
```

When the mouse leaves one of these elements ([`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)), similar to when it goes over them, except this time adding the class `sidenavOff` to that element.

---

You're close but probably want code that looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.sidenavOff").mouseover(function () { // add visibility flag
        $("div.sidenavOver").addClass("showme"); // to div.sidenavOver
    }).mouseout(function () { // remove visibility flag
        $("div.sidenavOver").removeClass("showme"); // from div.sidenavOver
    });
});
```

Where the class `showme` relates to some CSS to force the element to be displayed

```
.showme {display: block;}
```

Comment: I changed it to that and nada :/ Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are just trying to show or hide the "sidenavOver" div when the mouse hovers the container. Is that correct?

I created this jsfiddle using your html, but commented out all your missing images and added a class to your container div.
http://jsfiddle.net/joshvito/GaZQ6/

e.g.

```
//on hover over the container; you can use the a tag too, which ever element you want to bind the event to 
       $('.container').on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(".sidenavOff").hide(); //On mouseover, hode the first div
            $(".sidenavOver").show();
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(".sidenavOff").show();
            $(".sidenavOver").hide();
        }
    });
```

good reference for the js event handlers is at [JQUERY API Documentation for .on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: the fiddle above was meant to show you the application of the jquery principle. you need to apply it to your html/css